# Pasting multiple lines so that they consistently execute

Tags: bash, sudo, clipboard

Here's an example of a very simple code snippet that I'd like to paste to my terminal in a way that everything is executed.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade


sudo apt -y install build-essential
sudo apt -y install git
sudo apt -y install libxml2-dev # required for some tools using xml files

sudo apt autoremove
```

Unfortunately, what happens if build-essential wasn't installed beforehand is that it only runs until `sudo apt -y install build-essential`. The subsequent lines are skipped. The same is true if git wasn't installed: It'll run until the git line, then skip the rest.

What's the reason for this happening, and is there a way to fix this problem without having to create a script file and running it via bash?

Comment: Trying to understand... If the `build-essential` were to fail, would you want to continue executing the other items?

Comment: Also, since you're (probably) running these commands via `bash`, is there a particular problem with creating a script and running that?

Comment: Basically, I'm just trying to understand what it is exactly that prevents this snippet from being fully executed (line by line) by pasting it into the Unix terminal.

Comment: I have a collection of Unix shell snippets and I need to have a basic understanding of when pasting snippets into the terminal works, and when it doesn't.

Comment: does `apt install build-essential` prompt for input during the installation?

Comment: Well, it might be asking for the sudo password, depending on the state of the terminal.

Comment: The situation I'm imagining is where `sudo apt -y install build-essential` is prompting for some specific response (yes, no, something) and it gobbles up your subsequent pasted lines as garbage responses to its prompts, thus never completing.

Comment: Right, but that shouldn't happen because I'm using the `-y` option, which essentially forces a "yes" without required input.

Comment: Strike my idea, then. If there's enough time between "apt upgrade" and "buid-essential", you could be right about the sudo timestamp timing out.

Comment: There is obviously _something_ reading from standard input, which eats up the rest of the commands. I would paste it into `cat >script.sh` and then run that with `sh script.sh` instead.

Comment: Your comment about `-y` forcing apt is incorrect.

If the line `sudo apt install -y build-essentials` is causing a prompt for the sudo password, the apt parameters mean nothing at all yet. The SUDO command is asking for authentication before anything else is done with your input.

@JeffSchaller is correct, the following lines are being received by SUDO as the password input and causing the failure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are still within sudo's credential cache timeout (if you are unsure, just refresh it with `sudo -v` before running the snippet), that problem happens because apt(-get) is a very rich console application and thus consumes stdin even when it asks you nothing because of the `-y`.

You can work around that by running the whole snippet in a subshell:

At the prompt, start by typing a `(` then paste the snippet then type the closing `)` and press return

It should go.

Notice how the snippet is not executed as soon as you paste it. It rather gets “queued” on the command line, waiting for the closing parentheses.

(PS: depending on your system you may need to use `apt-get autoremove` in place of `apt autoremove`, and you may also need to use `-y` on `update` and `upgrade` too)

Comment: Awesome, that did it! So basically `sudo` and `apt` are complex commands that have a tendency to eat up input. Gotcha. Just one comment: `apt autoremove` exists and works.

Also, an alternative workaround I found is to concatenate the commands via `&&` (ensuring the next line always is only executed if the previous succeeded) and to either write all commands on a single line, or to use the escape character ``\``.

Comment: ugh.. It's really about time to update my system then.. `apt autoremove` does not work for me..! :-(

Comment: @Michael Of course those ways and a few others work too, but you wanted to just copy&paste it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If there is sufficient time between the `sudo apt upgrade` command and the `sudo apt install -y build-essentials` command, then SUDO will prompt for your password again.

Because you are pasting text into the console, the next line(s) will be accepted as STDIN to the SUDO prompt for a password. If the line does not match your password, authentication will fail and the `build-essentials` line will not be executed.